# @ConditionalOnExpression not working but @Value working

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have the need of enable/disable a @Aspect on a class in a Spring (non boot) application.

**Spring version is: 4.1.6.RELEASE**

I have a .properties file (*that we already use successfully in other point of the application, for example to select the log4j2 configuration file*) with the property `aspect.enabled=true|false` and I tried using the `@ConditionalOnExpression` annotation to enable|disable it.

This is my try:

application.properties file:

```
aspect.enabled=true
```

Class code:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = { "file:${catalina.home}/conf/application.properties" })
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${aspect.enabled}'=='true'")
@Aspect
@Component
public class TimingProfilerProduction {

    @Value("${aspect.enabled}")
    public String aspect;
```

With this configuration the expression is always evaluated to **false**.

I tried putting a single "true" to see if it works in this simple way:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = { "file:${catalina.home}/conf/application.properties" })
@ConditionalOnExpression("true")
@Aspect
@Component
public class TimingProfilerProduction {

    @Value("${aspect.enabled}")
    public String aspect;
```

Of course in this way the @ConditionalOnExpression gets evaluated to true and I can also prove that the *aspect* class property correctly reads the *aspect.enabled* property.

Try #3

I tried with a **@ConditionalOnProperty**:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = { "file:${catalina.home}/conf/application.properties" })
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix="aspect", name="enabled", havingValue = "true")
```

but nothing, always **false**.

Try #4:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${aspect.enabled}")
```

or

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("!${aspect.enabled}")
```

Gives an error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos 1): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
```

Try #5 (with default values):

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${aspect.enabled:true}")
```

always gives **true** (even with `aspect.enabled=false`), and accordingly

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${aspect.enabled:false}")
```

always gives **false**

Comment: Have you tried `@ConditionalOnProperty`?

Comment: Yes, @GrzegorzOledzki, I tried it but nothing (Try #3)

Comment: @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "aspect.enabled", matchIfMissing = false, havingValue = "true") have you tried like this?

Comment: @Ermintar is right, Please check the example [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty)

Comment: No i didn't with that exact wording, so I will and update the question accordingly. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${aspect.enabled}' == 'true'")
```

Try:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${aspect.enabled} == true")
```